# Can't store float values to sql server using npm mssql with Node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am trying to do simple UPDATE query and store a percentage value which will go in a percentage column that is of type float in my sql server database.

**When I do this:**

```
var percentage = 3.1415;
const updateAttendence = await sql.query `UPDATE Attendence SET percentage = ${ percentage } WHERE session_id =  ${ parseInt( req.body.session ) } AND student_id = ${ parseInt( req.body.AttendanceData[i].id ) } `;
```

**I get this in my database**

[image]

**and when I do this - replace `percentage = ${ percentage }` with `percentage = 3.1415`**

```
const updateAttendence = await sql.query `UPDATE Attendence SET percentage = 3.1415 WHERE session_id = 1  AND student_id = 1 `
```

**I get what i wanted with** **`percentage = ${ percentage }`**

[image]

I don't get it why its not working as it suppose to. Is it just me or anyone else having this issue and what are the solutions to such a simple thing becoming a problem ( well at least for me ).

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `node-mssql` that assumes that numeric values are Ints. You can specify the value as something else using the `.input` method, but then you can't use the tagged template literal.

```
const updateAttendence = await pool.request()
  .input('percentage', sql.Float, percentage)
  .input('session_id', sql.Int, req.body.session)
  .input('student_id', sql.Int, req.body.AttendanceData[i].id)
  .query(`UPDATE Attendence SET percentage = @percentage
  WHERE session_id =  @session_id
  AND student_id = @student_id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in case of **decimal**

```
.input('percentage',sql.Decimal(6,2),req.body.percentage)
```